# Como fazer para quando clicar em um item de um menu a aba receber a view correspondente em angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Bom galera eu estou começando a estudar angularjs, e na minha aplicação eu queria fazer algo parecido com o seguinte.

Tenho um menu dropdown e também tenho umas tabs que eu criei manualmente. Ao clicar em um item do menu eu queria fazer com que essa tab recebesse a view porem  eu não estou conseguindo.O máximo que eu fiz foi ao clicar na aba mudar o conteúdo correspondente usando as rotas.

segue a baixo o código que eu já fiz só do html supondo que eu tenho uma parte de rotas já pronta.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#create">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#list">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#list">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-init="tab=1">
    <ul class="tabs-nav">
        <li><a ng-click="tab=1" href="#edit" ng-class="{'active' : tab==1}">Aba 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="tab=2" href="#list" ng-class="{'active' : tab==2}">Aba 2</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="tab=3" href="#create" ng-class="{'active' : tab==3}">Aba 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 1">
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 2">
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 3">
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

É um exemplo básico mais o que eu estou fazendo é o seguinte, tenho umas abas e nessas abas quando eu clico nelas ela carregam o conteúdo até ai ok. Porem o que eu queria é ao clicar no link do menu uma das abas recebesse a view que eu configuraria. Como citei anteriormente eu estou utilizando as rotas para mudar clicando nas abas so queria fazer pelo menu não estou conseguindo linkar o menu com as abas. Se alguém tiver uma solução para isso agradeço.

Comment: Qual sistema de rota você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando o ui-router app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)  ai tem os seguintes "states", list create e edit com os controllers e views correspondentes.

Comment: Você não pode colocar o template direto no html? ou um ng-include?

Comment: Já tentou isso? `/#edit`, `/#create`, `/#list`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade foi o que eu pensei porem essa a questão não estou conseguindo referenciar o botão do menu com a aba.Ao clicar no item do menu la na minha aba 1 por exemplo a view ser chamada.

IvanFerrer é exatamente isso que estou fazendo hoje, porem isso que estou fazendo é nas abas ao clicar na propria aba abre a rota /#edit e etc. Queria clicar no menu e em uma das abas aparecer a view  de um formulario.

A questão é como vincular o item do menu a uma aba.

Comment: `<a href="/#edit">Editar</a>` ? Na verdade vc tem que colocar a barra logo que entra na página. sua index tem sempre que ter uma barra/ O problema é que a rota do angular faz uso de cerquilha, e confunde um pouco com apontamento na mesma página.

Comment: @IvanFerrer isso, porem ao clicar em um dos itens la no dropdown menu aparecer em uma das abas a view que eu configurar nas rotas.

Comment: Sua url tem que ficar mais ou menos assim:  www.site.com.br/home/#/edit

Comment: Fiz com os dois modos para você @DaviPereira veja se algum atende sua necessidade.

Comment: Não sei qual o problema exatamente que você está tendo, mas aqui num sistema que fiz, funciona normal...

Comment: @ivanFerrer testarei e logo mais postarei o resultado grato pela ajuda. Em breve atualizarei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução usando o router, poderia ser da seguinte maneira:

```
.state('tab', {
    abstract: true, //não permite acessar diretamente esse view, deve ser um child
    views: {
        "tab": {
            controller: 'MeuCtrl',
            templateUrl: "seu/caminho/arquivo.html"
        }
    }
})
    .state('edit', {
        parent: 'tab',
        url: '/Tab1',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: templateUrl: "seu/caminho/edit.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('list', {
        parent: 'tab',
        url: '/Tab1',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: templateUrl: "seu/caminho/list.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('create', {
        parent: 'tab',
        url: '/Tab1',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: templateUrl: "seu/caminho/create.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

E no seu html:

```
<ul class="tabs-nav">
    <li><a ng-click="tab=1" ui-sref="edit" ng-class="{'active' : tab==1}">Aba 1</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="tab=2" ui-sref="list" ng-class="{'active' : tab==2}">Aba 2</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="tab=3" ui-sref="create" ng-class="{'active' : tab==3}">Aba 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Repare que o state tab tem o abstract true, ou seja, ele nunca pode ser acessado diretamente, você deve acessar um dos "state child".

Ps.: a view `tab` seria para conter todo o html que está na sua questão. Ou se você já usa a view `main` para isso, apenas crie uma view secundária para usar só para as tabs. Se fizer isso, não se esqueça de mudar no view dos childs na rota também.

---

Se você deseja usar diretamente no html, sem o route, também é possível, basta usar o li sem a propriedade href, e adicione um ng-include direto no template. Repare que ele precisa ter aspas duplas e simples.

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 1">
        <div ng-include="'seu/caminho/arquivo1.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 2">
        <div ng-include="'seu/caminho/arquivo2.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-show="tab == 3">
        <div ng-include="'seu/caminho/arquivo3.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternativa para o ng-include:

```
<ng-include src="'seu/caminho/arquivo3.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: muito bom entendi perfeitamente. Porem queria saber so mais uma coisa eu tenho um Botão com um menu dropdown  e cada item desse menu é referente a uma aba como eu faço para vincular esse item do menu a essa aba? Exemplo: Um dos itens do menu é o item create ao clicar no item create no menu la na aba 1 por exemplo aparecer a view. Agora ja entendi essa parte do ng-include e do ui-router agora so queria vincular o meu menu dropdown com as tabs.

Comment: Se você está usando o router, basta por o ui-sref lá também, se não, basta por o ng-click="tab = X" nesse menu. Se entendi bem sua dúvida, seria isso :)

Comment: isso mesmo vou testar e logo logo coloco  a resposta. Estou no trabalho porem muito obrigado pela ajuda. Logo mais darei retorno.

Comment: Ok. Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas informações me foi muito util, estou vendo se consigo fazer algumas coisinhas a mais com isso caso tenho alguma duvida volto a perguntar. Muito grato pela resposta me serviu bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Faça mais ou menos assim e veja se resolve:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);

var url = window.location.href;
var levels = url.split('/');

if (levels[4] == 'edit' || levels[4] == 'list' || levels[4] == 'create') {
    angularApp.config([
                         '$routeProvider',
                         function ($routeProvider) {
                            $routeProvider
                            .when("/", {templateUrl: "/template/sua_template1.html",acao_1:" active"})
                            .when("/home", {templateUrl: "/template/sua_template2.html",acao_2:" active"})
                            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home/'});
                         }
                     ]);

}
```